# how to stop an svg css animation?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG animation and I'm trying to figure out how to stop and leave the SVG in view right after the animation sequence is completed once. This way the logo stays on the page until the next page refresh etc.

**here's the demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/u410bjyk/

**html:**

```
    <svg class="pin" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1">
  <g class="pin__group">
    <g class="pin__grayGroup">
      <path class="pin__square" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,0 0,60 60,60 60,0z"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M15,0 15,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M30,0 30,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,0 45,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,45 60,45"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,30 60,30"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,15 60,15"/>
      <path class="pin__circleBig" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M60,30 a30,30 0 0,1 -60,0 a30,30 0 0,1 60,0"/>
      <path class="pin__circleSmall" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
    <g class="pin__greenGroup">
      <path class="pin__outer" stroke-width="2" d="M30,0 a30,30 0 0,1 30,30 L60,60 30,60 a30,30 0 0,1 0,-60"/>
      <path class="pin__inner" stroke-width="2" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.pin__group {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 30px;
          transform-origin: 30px 30px;
  -webkit-animation: group-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: group-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__grayGroup {
  -webkit-animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__square {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 240, 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  -webkit-animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__line {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 60, 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60;
}
.pin__line-1 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
}
.pin__line-2 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
}
.pin__line-3 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleBig {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 188.522, 188.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  -webkit-animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleSmall {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__outer {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 201.391, 201.391;
  stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  -webkit-animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__inner {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I know I can remove the "infinite" property to run it once, but the question is, how do you stop it right after instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pause a CSS animation by using:

```
animation-play-state: paused;
```

I've added a button to your example that lets you stop the animation at any point.

```js
function stop() {
  $(".pin__group, .pin__grayGroup, .pin__square, .pin__line-1, .pin__line-2, .pin__line-3, .pin__circleBig, .pin__circleSmall, .pin__outer, .pin__inner").addClass("stop");
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.pin__group {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 30px;
          transform-origin: 30px 30px;
  -webkit-animation: group-anim 8s 1s forwards;
          animation: group-anim 8s 1s forwards;
}
.pin__grayGroup {
  -webkit-animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__square {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 240, 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  -webkit-animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__line {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 60, 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60;
}
.pin__line-1 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
}
.pin__line-2 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
}
.pin__line-3 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleBig {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 188.522, 188.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  -webkit-animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleSmall {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__outer {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 201.391, 201.391;
  stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  -webkit-animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__inner {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}
@keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}

.stop {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="pin" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1">
  <g class="pin__group">
    <g class="pin__grayGroup">
      <path class="pin__square" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,0 0,60 60,60 60,0z"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M15,0 15,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M30,0 30,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,0 45,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,45 60,45"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,30 60,30"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,15 60,15"/>
      <path class="pin__circleBig" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M60,30 a30,30 0 0,1 -60,0 a30,30 0 0,1 60,0"/>
      <path class="pin__circleSmall" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
    <g class="pin__greenGroup">
      <path class="pin__outer" stroke-width="2" d="M30,0 a30,30 0 0,1 30,30 L60,60 30,60 a30,30 0 0,1 0,-60"/>
      <path class="pin__inner" stroke-width="2" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: sorry if Im dense! but how would I apply that to end of the animation when the green pin is displayed? without user interaction...

Comment: You could use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: thank-you! I ended up using setTimeout(). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.